# Cytoscape layout to use node attributes as coordinates?

Tags: cytoscape

Is there a way to use x,y coordinates stored as attributes of each node to layout a graph using the coordinates that were calculated by another program?

And if not, would it be possible to implement this somehow - how does one get started on this?

Is there a standard way how to provide the node positions to the cytoscape.js web viewer somehow?

Background: it is trivial to use Python networkx to calculate some layouts which are not supported in Cytoscape, and it would also be trivial to store the coordinates as node attributes. All that would then be need is some way for Cytoscape to use those coordinates to find node positions instead of using a layout algorithm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a quite easy thing to do. Many examples on  use this functionlity in the demos, as you can see here:

- 1: [FCose Demo](https://github.com/iVis-at-Bilkent/cytoscape.js-fcose/blob/master/demo.html)
- 2: [Cose Blicent Demo](https://github.com/cytoscape/cytoscape.js-cose-bilkent)
- 3: [d3-force Demo](https://github.com/shichuanpo/cytoscape.js-d3-force)
- 4: [Euler Compound Demo](https://github.com/cytoscape/cytoscape.js-euler)
- 5: [Spread Demo](https://github.com/cytoscape/cytoscape.js-spread)

As you can see, there are an abundance of examples for this in the demos, but also in the docs. You can see one [here](https://js.cytoscape.org/#notation/position) and [here](https://js.cytoscape.org/#notation/elements-json):

```
// can use reference to eles later
var eles = cy.add([
  { group: 'nodes', data: { id: 'n0' }, position: { x: 100, y: 100 } },
  { group: 'nodes', data: { id: 'n1' }, position: { x: 200, y: 200 } },
  { group: 'edges', data: { id: 'e0', source: 'n0', target: 'n1' } }
]);
```

The json used in the `.add()` function can be created in your js application or directly in Python and added to the graph as some of the examples do.

In general, you should take some time and skim through through the docs. The ability to position nodes via **x** and **y** is quite basic and is one of the first pages in the docs.

If you don't understand the description in the docs and the examples I provided, please edit your question and add your current code as a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), where you can show your efforts to implement the positioning.

---

### **Edit:**

As @maxkfranz pointed out, the [preset layout](https://js.cytoscape.org/#layouts/preset) plays a big role here. The documentation states this in the [Initialisation Chapter](https://js.cytoscape.org/#core/initialisation):

- **If you want to specify your node positions yourself in your elements JSON, you can use the preset layout — by default it does not set any positions, leaving your nodes in their current positions (i.e. specified in options.elements at initialisation time)**.`

Comment: It may be worth also mentioning the use of the preset layout at init

Answer (score 1):

I am new to using Cytoscape so things that are "easy" are not so easy for me. I often don't even know the right way to ask a question. Everyone has things that are hard and things that are easy, and step by step we expand our knowledge so what is hard today may be easy tomorrow.

Anyway, here is something that may be a part of the solution you are looking for:

In the Cytoscape desktop application, you can create a "Style" that maps a node attribute to "X Location" and another node attribute to "Y Location".